# ng-if to Show Default Value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a data structure like this:

```
$scope.classes = [
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'101'},
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'102'},
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'103'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'111'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'112'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'113'}];

$scope.professors = [
      {Dept:'Science', Class:null, Name:'John Smith'},
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'101', Name:'Eric Doe'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:null, Name:'Mary Smith'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'111', Name:'Frank Moore'}
    ]
```

I want to show the professor's name when the Dept and Class both match. If not, show the professor's name for that Dept (with Class=null).

However, my result looks like this:

```
Dept:Science   Dept:Science   Dept:Science   Dept:Arts   Dept:Arts   Dept:Arts
Class:101      Class:102      Class:103      Class:111   Class:112   Class:113

John Smith     John Smith     John Smith     Mary Smith  Mary Smith  Mary Smith
Eric Doe                                     Frank Moore
```

How do I make the result look like:

```
Dept:Science  Dept:Science  Dept:Science  Dept:Arts   Dept:Arts   Dept:Arts
Class:101     Class:102     Class:103     Class:111   Class:112   Class:113

Eric Doe      John Smith    John Smith    Frank Moore Mary Smith  Mary Smith
```

Here's my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dw9y0vz1/1/)

Comment: water42, what I'm trying to do is to show the right professor name when both of his/her Dept and Class Name match the ones from the classes collection. And show the default professor name when only the Dept name matches (with the Class Name = null).

Comment: `<div ng-if="prof.Class === null && !$scope.hasProfessor(class)`, where `$scope.hasProfessor(class)` searches `$scope.professors` to see the class already has a professor associated with it. This would be faster if you could add another property to `$scope.classes.class`, `hasProfessor`, and set that to `true` when the first `ng-if` triggers. Then instead of a function you could do `<div ng-if="prof.Class === null && !class.hasProfessor`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to **@water42** for giving the idea for the possible solution.

I tried it out and it works.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.classes = [
     {Dept:'Science', Class:'101'},
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'102'},
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'103'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'111'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'112'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'113'}];
    
    $scope.professors = [
     {Dept:'Science', Class:null, Name:'John Smith'},
      {Dept:'Science', Class:'101', Name:'Eric Doe'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:null, Name:'Mary Smith'},
      {Dept:'Arts', Class:'111', Name:'Frank Moore'}
    ];
    
    $scope.classes = $scope.classes.map(function(roomClass) {
       var professor_count = $scope.professors.filter(function(professor) {
            return professor.Class === roomClass.Class;
         });
         roomClass.hasProfessor = professor_count.length > 0;
         return roomClass;
    });
    
    console.log($scope.classes);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
       <table>
        <tr>
          <th width="10%" ng-repeat="class in classes track by $index">
            Dept:{{class.Dept}} <br/>
            Class:{{class.Class}}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%" ng-repeat="class in classes track by $index">
            <div ng-repeat="prof in professors" ng-if="prof.Dept === class.Dept">
              <div ng-if="class.hasProfessor && prof.Class === class.Class">
                  {{prof.Name}}
              </div>
               <div ng-if="!class.hasProfessor && prof.Class === null">
                  {{prof.Name}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>          
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```